# firebase android having trouble retrieving a list of children at a specific location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve a list of children at a specific location, but I get only gibberish when I do what I think is right.

My code for retrieving data:

```
final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            adapter.add(dataSnapshot.child(userId).getChildren().toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            adapter.add(dataSnapshot.child(userId).getChildren().toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            adapter.add(dataSnapshot.child(userId).getChildren().toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to load entries.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

Screenshot of datastructure
[image: datastructure]

What I am trying to retrieve a list of the children below the userId.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use [`.getValue()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()) to on the data you get from firebase to see the data you need

Comment: tried using .getValue() instead of .getChildren(), but that crashes because of a  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should add the `ChildEventListener` to the root node of your firebase database since this would download all the data in your database.

Instead, call it on the specific user since you only want it for that UID.

```
final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userId);


ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        // maybe use a POJO here to collect data easily
        // the toString() method is maybe for testing??
        adapter.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        // This part should have appropriate code
        // Unless of course you actually want to add it
        //to the adapter everytime
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This part should have appropriate code
        // Unless of course you actually want to add it
        //to the adapter everytime
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to load entries.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

Comment: tried the changes you suggested now, but that just throws a new error. it says throwable java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Does this mean i actually get everything below userId back? i just want the first child below userId..

Comment: You should really use a POJO to store the incoming data. You only want the first child?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the slow response, I have been away for a few days. Yes i just want a list of the first children below the userID. I am not sure what a POJO is or how to do it.... Yes, I'm a noob..

Comment: You probably do know what a POJO (plain old Java object) is. By the first children, do you mean you want all the dates? If you do, your going to end up downloading everything under the user ID because it'll download everything under the dates too

Comment: I solved this in another way, by saving a seperate list of dates to firebase, and getting them from there. :)